# How to animate tabbar badge count in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, uitabbarcontroller

I want to animate badge count over tabbar something like Bouncing Animation . Has anyone implemented it with native UITabBarController . i am not using any third party class for adding UITabBarController in my project.

Comment: I dont think you can animate the default method of setting the count.. you might have to create your own custom view and then add animation to it

Comment: @RakshithNandish is right, you probably have to do it manually. Are you open to use `pods` for it?

Comment: You can, I guess designing it should not take you long.. give it a try. Let me know how that goes

Comment: Actually my project is completed , only thing pending is animation on that badge. To achieve this manually ,i have to make much changes to have tabbarcotroller like working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i do some thing like this before i will share the code with you 
 first i create two functions 
first one is :

```
func loopThrowViews(view:UIView){
    for subview in (view.subviews){
        let type = String(describing: type(of: subview))
        print(type)
        if type == "_UIBadgeView" {
            print("this is BadgeView")
            animateView(view: subview)
        }
         else {
            loopThrowViews(view:subview)
        }

    }
}
```

this function take view  and loop throw all its subViews  until it find the badge View  then it's call the animate method  this one

```
  func animateView(view:UIView){
let shakeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
shakeAnimation.duration = 0.05
shakeAnimation.repeatCount = 50
shakeAnimation.autoreverses = true
shakeAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x:view.center.x - 10, y:view.center.y))
shakeAnimation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x:view.center.x + 10, y:view.center.y))
view.layer.add(shakeAnimation, forKey: "position")
}
```

You can replace the code at this method with your own animation

all what you need is to call this method like this when ever you want to animate  the badge

```
 loopThrowViews(view: self.tabBarController!.tabBar)
```

the result will be like this

[image]

full example here https://github.com/AliAdam/AnimateTabbarBadgeView

Comment: Worked Perfectly :)

Comment: check the github project i create an extension  just drop it on your project and call the method  like the example

Comment: Yes i used that category file to achieve animation for badge.

Comment: i got  Variable used within its own initial value in line **String(describing: type(of: subview))**, plz help